# Find first value in run but allowing for exceptions

Tags: r

I have this dataframe which contains different `id`'s. Each `id` has a run value that increase consecutively from 1.  There are 3 values associated with each run - these may be `NaN`:

```
    val1 runno id val2 val3
1  -0.20     1  P 0.62    6
2  -0.25     2  P 0.43   10
3   0.16     3  P 0.32   40
4   0.31     4  P 0.00   98
5  -0.33     5  P 0.30   10
6   0.18     6  P 0.13   67
7   0.34     7  P 0.03   40
8   0.16     8  P 0.22   62
9   0.20     9  P 0.07   80
10  0.54    10  P 0.05   13
11  1.00    11  P 0.16    2
12  0.35     1  Q 0.35    7
13  0.45     2  Q 0.27    6
14   NaN     3  Q  NaN    3
15  0.67     4  Q 0.14    5
16  1.00     5  Q 0.03    5
17  0.73     6  Q 0.00   20
18  0.71     7  Q 0.08    6
19  0.49     8  Q 0.17    8
20  0.62     9  Q 0.03   13
21  1.00    10  Q 0.08    3
22  0.36     1  R 0.05   29
23 -0.10     2  R 0.67   18
24 -0.07     3  R 0.74   23
25 -0.18     4  R 0.44   19
26 -0.24     5  R 0.29   20
27 -0.07     6  R 0.82   11
28  0.15     7  R 0.51   19
29 -0.04     8  R 0.84   26
30  0.17     9  R 0.28   38
31  0.51     1  S 0.07   13
32   NaN     2  S  NaN    4
33  0.29     3  S 0.34   11
34  0.45     4  S 0.27    6
35  0.63     5  S 0.00   24
36  0.32     6  S 0.00  136
37 -1.00     1  T 0.16    2
38   NaN     2  T  NaN    2
39   NaN     3  T  NaN    6
40   NaN     4  T  NaN    5
41  0.48     5  T 0.00   62
42  0.36     1  U 0.00  149
43  0.33     2  U 0.11   24
44  0.75     3  U 0.04    8
45  1.00     4  U 0.01    6
46   NaN     5  U  NaN    5
```

I want to find the index of each `id` that satisfies the following:

- every run after it within its `id` has a positive value of `val1` or a `NaN` value of val1.
- every run after it within its `id` has a value of `val2` that is less than 0.1, or is `NaN`.
- if the value of `val3` is < 5 and `val1` is still positive, then these rows can be 'omitted' from the second rule requiring a `val2` of <.01.  e.g. Take "P" - on `runno==11` it has a `val3` of 2 and a `val1` of 1.00. Therefore its `val2` of >0.1 is ignored and that row can be included in a continuous run.
- A final rule is that whilst `NaN` values can be ignored to continue a run (as long as `val1` is positive), the run cannot start with them. For instance, for `id==T` - the final value at `runno==5` is `val1=0.48` and `val2=0.00`. The runs for 2,3,4 are all `NaN` but run 1 has a negative value of `val1`.  Therefore we must say the start of this run is '5' and not '2' as it cannot start on a `NaN`.  If row 1 had been positive for `val1`, then we could have called that the start.
- finally, if there is no run that satisfies the above criteria, then NA should be returned -e.g. `id=="R"`

For the above dataframe, this is what I believe to be the indices satisfying the above criteria:

```
#P-9, Q-9, R-NA, S-5, T-5, U-3
```

I have been running in circles a bit, but this is my thinking so far:

```
#Make a vector for rows that satisfy the `val1` and `val2` criteria:
x <- ifelse(newdf$val1>0 & newdf$val2<0.1, 1, 0) 
[1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1
```

Add back in the `NA` values so they can be ignored (this is a problem for situations when we want to ignore them if there is no '1' prior to the NA).

```
x[is.na(x)]<-1
```

Add back in a 1, if `val3` is <5 but `val1` is still positive

```
x[newdf$val3 < 5  & newdf$val1>0]<-1
```

Now split this by `id`:

```
sp <- split(x, as.character(newdf$id))


   $P
 [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1

$Q
 [1] 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1

$R
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$S
[1] 1 1 0 0 1 1

$T
[1] 0 1 1 1 1

$U
[1] 1 0 1 1 1
```

Count positive runs of each vector, resetting at 1 after each 0:

```
lapply(sp, function(x) ifelse(x==0, 0, unlist(sapply(rle(x)$lengths, function(x) {return(1:x)}))))



  $P
 [1] 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 2 3

$Q
 [1] 0 0 1 0 1 2 3 0 1 2

$R
[1] 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

$S
[1] 1 2 0 0 1 2

$T
[1] 0 1 2 3 4

$U
[1] 1 0 1 2 3
```

Find index of first '1' that continues as a positive run until end of the vector-  return an NA if no such solution exists:

```
unlist(lapply(spc, function(x)  ifelse(x[length(x)]==0, NA, ifelse(all(x)==T,  1, rev(which((x>0)==F))[[1]] + 1 )) ) )


P  Q  R  S  T  U 
9  9 NA  5  2  3
```

For "T" it is starting with the first NA. I think this us because I didn't conditionally replace the NA with 1 depending on whether there existed any 1 prior to the NA.

I'm interested in any solution to this-  or to improve the general running of the algorithm.